# The app gets frozen when returning a custom UIView as a marker infoWindow (Google Maps iOS SDK)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a custom `UIView` (with a `xib`, `.h` and `.m` files) and I want it to be my `GMSMarker`'s info window. But when I return my custom `UIView` in the `-mapView: markerInfoWindow:` method, the app just gets frozen and stuck (it's not even crashing).

My code is:

```
-(UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
    //Creating "infoWindow"(infoWindow) and setting it with nib file called "infoWindow"
    CustomMarkerInfoWindow *infoWindow=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomMarkerInfoWindow" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

    //Returning "infoWindow"(infoWindow)
    return infoWindow;
}
```

I have no idea why it's freezing and I know for sure that this code worked in the past, so I can't understand what's wrong.

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the app freezing up where you create the `CustomMarkerInfoWindow` object?

Comment: Regardless, run the code and when it freezes, pause the app in the debugger and look at the stack trace. You'll be able to see exactly what's stuck

Comment: @laynemoseley No, it's freezing up when I return the object, it's really weird because if I create another `UIView` (for example: `TestView`) it's all working fine

Comment: @laynemoseley How can I get this stack trace?

Comment: @laynemoseley I think I found it, it crashes at the end with `Thread 23: signal SIGBART`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS app freezes when loading custom info window for marker on Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746786/ios-app-freezes-when-loading-custom-info-window-for-marker-on-google-maps)

Answer (score 0):

Put this method in your custom view implementation file

```
-(void)didMoveToSuperview{
    self.superview.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
}
```