# iOS app freezes when loading custom info window for marker on Google Maps

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to implement a custom info window on my Google Maps Marker on an iOS app. (As is done [here](http://sweettutos.com/2015/12/14/how-to-make-a-custom-info-window-for-your-marker-with-google-maps-sdk-for-ios/) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILiBXYscsyYh-google-maps-sdk-for-ios/) for example.)

I have created a xib and a `UIView` class for it. It is called `CustomInfoWindow.xib` and the class is `CustomInfoWindow.swift`.

My Custom Info Window is currently blank, i.e. I have not yet added any `UIControl`s to my xib. I have also not yet added any code to my class file.

The `CustomInfoWindow.swift` file basically looks like:

```
import UIKit
class CustomInfoWindow: UIView {}
```

In my ViewController for my maps my `markerInfoWindow` method is as follows:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker!) -> UIView! {
    let customInfoWindow = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindow", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! CustomInfoWindow

    return customInfoWindow
}
```

When I run the code and I click on one of my markers, the blank `CustomInfoWindow` displays fine.

The strange thing is that the moment I add any UI Element to the `CustomInfoWindow.xib` in the Interface Builder and run my app again then suddenly when I click on a marker the app freezes. (For example when I add a `UILabel` or a `UIImage` to the `CustomInfoWindow.xib`.) If I remove the UI Element then the blank nib displays fine over the marker.

If I test my nib by adding it as a subview on some View Controller then it loads fine with my `UILabel` and `UIImage`. However, when I use that same nib in the `markerInfoWindow` the app freezes.

What can the problem be?

UPDATE:
This issue occurred on version 1.13 of the Google Maps SDK for iOS and it turned out to be a [bug on that version](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9525).

Comment: do you get any crash error?

Comment: no - the app just freezes on the simulator. When I set a breakpoint on "return customInfoWindow" then the breakpoint still gets hit but after that if I continue program execution it is frozen and I have to stop the simulator.

Comment: same issue with the device? cause it can be a simulator problem

Comment: Yes, the same happens when I test it on an actual device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same issue. It's a GoogleMaps's bug! 
Freezing apperrs in version 1.13.0.

You can use:

```
pod 'GoogleMaps', '1.12.3'
```

Comment: Do I just specify that version in my Podfile or do I have to do something else after that like an install or library downgrade or something? Just including the version in my Podfile does not solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I reported this issue to the google team: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9668&thanks=9668&ts=1462050943

Answer (score 1):

Found the proper workaround for 1.13

Add the following code to the subclass CustomInfoWindow

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        superview?.autoresizesSubviews = false;
}
```

Source: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9525